# Does section exist in NSIndexPath

Tags: objective-c, nsindexpath

How to check if a collection of NSIndexPath objects have item in a specific section? I don't care about the row, and want to know yes/no if it has items of a particular section.

As is, I have written out statically based on the number of rows in the program, so for instance, a section 0 with 3 rows looks like:

```
if ([array containsObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0]] || [array containsObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:1 inSection:0]] || [array containsObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:2 inSection:0]])
```

Comment: Surely you want `&&` instead of `||`!?

Comment: I just want a bool to return yes if any row exists in section, in other words if user selected a particular section

Comment: Then you use a loop from `0` to `N` and yield `YES` if you ever catch `[array containsObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0]` returning `YES`.

Comment: Thanks! extra words for min chars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `array` contains an array of `NSIndexPath` objects:

```
NSInteger someSection = ... // the section to check for
BOOL exists = NO;
for (NSIndexPath *path in array) {
    if (path.section == someSection) {
        exists = YES;
        break;
    }
}

if (exists) {
    // Yes, at least one of the index paths was for the desired section
}
```

Comment: I went with this approach using case statement. does quite well despite absence of class method for this message.